# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\todolist-v1\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Using EJS to create a to-do list using node js, express js. When I use other tags of EJS like this <%= tag
it works. But when I use a scriptlet tag for each line, an error pops up on my server.

ERROR:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\todolist-v1\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:661:12)
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:396:16)
    at handleCache (C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:233:18)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Ak\Desktop\todolist-v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
```

**CODE**

```
 

     <% for (var i=0; i<new.ListItems.length; i++) { %> 
        <li><%= newListItems[i] %></li>
    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array name is  `newListItems` change`new.ListItems` to `newListItems`

```
   <% for (var i=0; i<newListItems.length; i++) { %> 
        <li><%= newListItems[i] %></li>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I searched everything but the array name. My bad.